# Strict vs NonStrict NHibernate cache concurrency strategies

Tags: nhibernate, caching

This question is about the difference between ReadWrite and NonStrictReadWrite cache concurrency strategies for NHibernate's second level cache.

As I understand it, the difference between these two strategies is relevant when you have a distributed *replicated* cache - nonstrict won't guarantee that one cache has the exact same value as another cache, while strict read/write should - assuming the cache provider does the appropriate distributed locking.

The part I don't understand is how the strict vs nonstrict distinction is relevant when you have a single cache, or a distributed *partitioned* (non replicated) cache. Can it be relevant? It seems to me that in non replicated scenarios, the timestamps cache will ensure that stale results are not served.  If it can be relevant, I would like to see an example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you assume is right, in a single target/thread environment there's little difference.  However if you look at the cache providers there is a bit going on even in a multi-threaded scenario.

How an object is re-cached from it's modified state is different in the non-strict.  For example, if your object is much heftier to reload but you'd like it to after an update instead of footing the next user with the bill, then you'll see different performance with strict vs non-strict.  For example: non-strict simply dumps an object from cache after an update is performed...price is paid for the fetch on the next access instead of a post-update event handler.  In the strict model, the re-cache is taken care of automatically.  A similar thing happens with inserts, non-strict will do nothing where strict will go behind and load the newly inserted object into cache.

In non-strict you also have the possibility of a dirty read, since the cache isn't locked at the time of the read you would not see the result of another thread's change to the item.  In strict the cache key for that item would lock and you would be held up but see the absolute latest result.

So, even in a single target environment, if there is a large amount of concurrent reads/edits on objects then you have a chance to see data that isn't really accurate.

This of course becomes a problem when a save is performed and an edit screen is loading:  the person thinking they're editing the latest version of the object really isn't, and they're in for a nasty surprise when they try to save the edits to the stale data they loaded.

Comment: Thanks Nick, this was very helpful. I mistakenly assumed that the timestamp cache would prevent dirty reads, but I can see how this is not possible without locking the cache (which nonstrict will not do).

Answer (score 2):

I have created a post [here](http://anirbanchowdhury.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/hibernate-second-level-cache-ehcache/) explaining the differences. Please have a look and feel free to comment.